# Hand Mesh Stretching When I Bend Armatures

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, bones

I'm not really use to blender or 3D modeling. I created a hand rig (First Time) and when I bend armatures the hand mesh bends in ways I don't want it too.

Before:[image]

After:
[image]

Could somebody help me fix this?

Comment: You probably used assigning Automatic Weight when parented mesh to armature, that use generative interpolation. To adjust result - With Shift key select Armature, than Mesh. Switch to Weight Paint mode, select proper bone and paint over the bend part with brush's weight set to zero. If you are using Subdivision modifier for very lowers model, you would have to add some additional vertices to avoid your issue.